# Scope for association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Still feeling my way around ARs (Rails 3.2). In my `user.rb` model, I have this piece of code:

```
  def has_answered
    self.quizzes.where(finished: true).count != 0
  end
```

In English, I'd like to "check whether a user has answered a quiz".

I'd like to change it into a scope, something to the effect of `scope :has_answered, includes(:quizzes).where("(finished: true). count > ?", 0)`. I get syntax errors. I have a few questions:

1. Is this actually better (cleanliness, flexibility, etc).
2. Can I still refactor this to make it cleaner?

Comment: Are you looking for finished quizzes belonging to a user, or users who have a finished quiz?

Comment: Thanks @Jon, users who have finished a quiz. I should address the ambiguity though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation you're probably best either implementing a `counter_cache` for the number of completed quizzes by a user, or just adding a boolean field to the user model for something like `has_completed_a_quiz`.

This way you'll easily be able to add a scope to the user model without needing to scan another table within the DB which could grow to be a large table/slow query.

Comment: I agree, I feel like this is expensive when `quizzes` grow. Of the two, which would you recommend (are `counter_cache`s faster than just adding a boolean or the opposite?

Comment: A counter cache is only useful if you need to know how many quizzes a user has completed. Otherwise just go with a boolean field.